# Gravitational Chern-Simons term in metric fields

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, chern-simons-theory

The Chern-Simons gravitational term is
$$
S= \int_{\mathcal{M}} d^3 x \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} \Gamma_{\mu\sigma}^\lambda
\left( \partial_\nu \Gamma_{\rho\lambda}^\sigma +\frac{2}{3} \Gamma^\sigma_{\nu\tau} \Gamma^\tau_{\rho\lambda} \right)
$$
My puzzle is usually, when we are formulating Einstein gravity, we use Ricci SCALAR. When we are studying Gauss-Bonnet or other higher derivative gravity, we will use contraction of Ricci Tensor Or Riemann tensor like $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$.

What is the reason then for people use Levi-Civita connection $\Gamma_{\rho\lambda}^\sigma$ to formulate the Chern-Simons gravitational term? What is the form in terms of either metrics or Ricci scalar, Ricci tensor or the corresponding derivative of those?

Comment: See eq.(3) of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2562